# Which tool can I use for viewing WRX files?

Tags: activex, openedge, progress-4gl, ocx

I'm working with Progress-4GL, release 11.6, appBuilder and procedure editor.

While working with OCX components, a WRX-file gets automatically created by the appBuilder. I would like to see the content of that WRX-file.

Currently, I've found this website, which also mentions that Progress IDE should contain such a viewer, but even after checking all Pro*tools, I didn't find any tool.

Does anybody know which tool of the Progress-4GL appBuilder/procedure editor toolchain allows viewing WRX-files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you positive your not thinking about OCX:es? There's a Com Object Viewer for ActiveX automation and such!

Comment: @Jensd: pardon my ignorance, but I don't understand your remark. Are you saying "You can look for all OCX classes inside the mentioned viewer" or are you saying "Don't use ActiveX, use something else instead.". I've been looking into the OLEViewer and I don't find my OCX control (Microsoft Date and Time picker).

Comment: I'll post an answer describing that function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it indeed is an OCX you want to look into you can use the Com Object Viewer.

It can be found a couple of different ways.
Quick Access Search in Developer Studio:
[image]

Via Pro*Tools under the Tools menu in the AppBuilder

[image]

Once started you can use it to open OCXes and Automation Objects to look at the internal API's of those.

You need to locate the file it's stored in. This could be either by knowledge of it's location or other way. If you add an OCX to a ABL Windows/Dialog program you will see the location of the control there:

[image]

Then you can open it in the Com Object Viewer to see methods, events and such and also get some short coding help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to Progress Knowledgebase, WRX files contain only design and runtime license keys (if required by the ActiveX Controls) along with any custom property settings that were made to any ActiveX Control in the windows. WRX files do not contain any ABL source or .r code.

Comment: Do you have the link to that post in the Progress Knowledgebase?

Comment: site:knowledgebase.progress.com wrx
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/What-do-wrx-files-contain